# Project files missing in container DDEV / Typo3 Windows 10

Tags: typo3, ddev

I have `Docker Toolbox V18.03` running on a Windows 10 machine, together with `DDEV 1.0` and `Typo3`.
When I run `ddev start`, the containers are starting and I can access to the container with `ddev ssh`.
But the project files from my host are not copied to the container.

This solutions here [I get an `ngnix 403 Forbidden' when starting ddev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227365/i-get-an-ngnix-403-forbidden-when-starting-ddev) won't fix my issue ...

Answer (score 0):

That basically means that docker-toolbox is not mounting your project at all, and of course nothing about ddev can work in that case. On docker toolbox is often means that you're trying to use a path outside your home directory. I recommend you use your home directory if you're not. See also [How to use a directory outside C:\Users with Docker Toolbox on Windows/Docker for Windows](http://support.divio.com/local-development/docker/how-to-use-a-directory-outside-cusers-with-docker-toolbox-on-windowsdocker-for-windows)

I've seen these other reasons for this behavior on Windows with Docker:

1. Root password changed and docker needs to re-share filesystem (Easiest fix is to reset to factory defaults)
2. inadequate resources (memory usually) assigned to docker
3. Drive not shared in the first place (Docker for Windows)
4. Trying to share a network drive (Docker won't do it)

Also... If you have Win10 Pro or Enterprise, please try Docker for Windows (only after full uninstall of Docker Toolbox). Otherwise, restart (or reinstall) docker toolbox.

Try this simple test (from https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/docker_installation/#testing-your-docker-installation) once you have docker toolbox running. In the directory where you want to work (a ddev project directory, maybe your home directory), using git bash, you can:

```
docker run -t --rm -v /$PWD:/junk busybox ls //junk
```

You should see the contents of the current directory listed. If that works, it means docker is successfully mounting the directory you ran it in. If it doesn't work, it means docker and ddev can not work for you. But you'll get it working, probably by reinstalling docker toolbox. (Don't forget when uninstalling docker toolbox you have to `rm -r ~/.docker` as well.)

Comment: Edited to add the issue with Docker Toolbox being unwilling to mount outside user home directory.